# Tableau Desktop Dashboard Refresh

Tags: refresh, tableau-api, dashboard

we are using a Tableau Desktop with a dashboard. It works great unfortunately the refresh isn't reliable. Tableau is connected to one Database with multiple SQL queries. All sheets are set to live mode.

When hitting the button "Refresh all Thumbnails":

[image]

Tableau sometimes updates only parts of the Dashboard, or sometimes it doesn't do anything although by going to the sheet and pressing F5 updates the data.

Is there a workaround for that? Or maybe even something that can run in the background and update the Dashboard every few minutes?

Thanks a lot for any hint!

PS: Machine is Windows 10 with Tableau version 2018.2.13

Comment: If you are refreshing the data even while the connection is live then why not create an extract and refresh that. Its much more reliable. Alternatively, if you are using Tableau server, publish data source extract there and set it to refresh as required.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using Alteryx to connect to your database (using Input Tool) and publish the .tde files to Tableau server via "Publish to Tableau server" macro.
You may then have a live connection to these .tde files and schedule the Alteryx workflow to refresh the .tde published on the Tableau server.

This would save lot of Tableau server resources and resolve the refresh issue as well.
Alteryx is an easy to use and powerful tool, in case you are not familiar with it. Below links may be helpful in guiding you through the process:

https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Knowledge-Base/How-To-Connect-to-an-Oracle-Database-in-Alteryx/ta-p/46654#targetText=Add%20an%20Input%20tool%20to%20the%20canvas,%20and%20select%20Oracle,Database%20Connection%20window%20will%20appear.

Link of "Publish to Tableau server" macro:
https://gallery.alteryx.com/#!app/Publish-to-Tableau-Server-Tool/599c93c8f499c7141c13a619